# Add html em texto com http em tabela usando jquery

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber o seguinte. Estou usando php que cria o código dentro de uma tabela dinamicamente e eu não consigo atribuir com jquery tag  quando for http ou https.

Meu código gerado em html:

```
<div id="profile-content-group_6282e2e909d66" class="profile-content-settings">
    <table class="profile-fields-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="label">Cidade</td>
            <td class="data">porto alegre</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Site</td>
            <td class="data">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Rede social</td>
            <td class="data">http://localhost/alianca/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Rede social</td>
            <td class="data">https://localhost/alianca/</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

A lógica é quando tiver um:

```
<td class="data">http://localhost/projeto/</td>
```

ficar assim:

```
<td class="data"><a href="http://localhost/projeto/">http://localhost/projeto/</a></td>
```

Comment: Vc disse que está usando `PHP` para gerar a tabela dinamicamente, pode postar esse trecho de código?

Comment: Não tem como pois ele vem de um plugin - wordpress

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: A necessidade acima é em jquery, fiz um exemplo no [link](https://jsfiddle.net/NTHWEB/z2guyqbh/3/) pois o que preciso é inserir tag's do tipo <a>que pega o texto já printado no DOM e jogá-lo no href dessa tag `<a href="minha url da tabela">minha url da tabela</a>`

Answer (score -1):

Eu entendi que vc quer alterar uma `tag html` inserindo um `link` e para isso usar `JQuery`, haja vista que vc disse que tem **isso**:

```
<td class="data"> http://localhost/projeto/ </td>
```

Mas quer chegar **nisso**:

```
<td class="data">
    <a href="http://localhost/projeto/"> http://localhost/projeto/ </a>
</td>
```

Penso que seria muito mais fácil se cada `td` tivesse um `#id`, pois com apenas a classe `.data` não consegui chegar no resultado que acredito ser o que vc espera.

Usando `Jquery` e `Javascript` puro, peguei o `td` verifiquei se ele contém a `string http ou https`, mas como não há o `#id` não consegui inserir a `tag a` apenas onde estão as `url`.

Como a tabela foi renderizada no `server-side`, utilizei o evento `load` da `window` para provocar a mudança sem recarregar a página.

```
<script>
        //dispara a ação ao carregar a tela
        $(window).on('load', () => {
            //cria uma variável que armazenará todos os ´td´
            let td = document.querySelectorAll('.data')
            //percorre a variável td testando se existe a string http ou https
            td.forEach(element => {
                //cria uma variável temporária para armazenar o conteúdo html da tag td
                let teste = element.innerHTML
                //verificar se a string http ou https está contida na variável teste
                if (teste.indexOf("http://") != -1 || teste.indexOf("https://") != -1) {
                    /**
                     * Substitui o conteúdo html da tag td com a classe data pelo link
                     * Aqui está o problema, como todas as tags td possuem a classe data
                     * A alteração não é a esperada
                     */
                    $('.data').html(`<a href='${teste}'>${teste}</a>`)
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Portanto, o mais próximo que consegui chegar até agora foi isso.
Aqui o código para teste:

```js
        //dispara a ação ao carregar a tela
        $(window).on('load', () => {
            //cria uma variável que armazenará todos os ´td´
            let td = document.querySelectorAll('.data')
            //percorre a variável td testando se existe a string http ou https
            td.forEach(element => {
                //cria uma variável temporária para armazenar o conteúdo html da tag td
                let teste = element.innerHTML
                //verificar se a string http ou https está contida na variável teste
                if (teste.indexOf("http://") != -1 || teste.indexOf("https://") != -1) {
                    /**
                     * Substitui o conteúdo html da tag td com a classe data pelo link
                     * Aqui está o problema, como todas as tags td possuem a classe data
                     * A alteração não é a esperada
                     */
                    $('.data').html(`<a href='${teste}'>${teste}</a>`)
                }
            })
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-content-group_6282e2e909d66" class="profile-content-settings">
        <table class="profile-fields-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="">
                    <td class="label">Cidade</td>
                    <td class="data">porto alegre</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Site</td>
                    <td class="data">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Rede social</td>
                    <td class="data">http://localhost/alianca/</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Rede social</td>
                    <td class="data">https://localhost/alianca/</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta Freba!! Realmente esse é o caminho, tentei evoluir o queryselect pois está pegando outra tabela com a mesma estrutura e sim! realmente tem que ter uma identificação no TD pra não acontecer isso. O https ele tmb não diferencia ainda, assim como subscreve outros campos.